# Basic MySQL Table Join?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL query multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572204/sql-query-multiple-tables)

I have these 2 tables:

ASSOCIATION_TABLE: [id, key, name, manager, office, bank, customer]

and

OFFICE_TABLE:  [id, name, address, phone]

I am currently running this query to get a data set that I need:

```
SELECT `name`, `key`, `office`, `manager`, `id` 
FROM `database`.`ASSOCIATION_TABLE`
WHERE `association`.`customer`=4;
```

How can I modify this query to display the NAME from the OFFICE_TABLE, rather than the ID?  I think a table join is my solution, but I'm nut sure what kind, or how exactly to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `name`, `key`, ot.name AS OFFICE_NAME, `manager`, `id` 
  FROM `ASSOCIATION_TABLE` at
       LEFT OUTER JOIN OFFICE_TABLE ot
       ON ot.id = at.office
 WHERE `association`.`customer`=4;
```

That's an outer join to OFFICE_TABLE. Your resultset will include any records in the ASSOCIATION_TABLE that do not have records in OFFICE_TABLE.

If you only want to return results with records in OFFICE_TABLE you will want an inner join, e.g.:

```
SELECT `name`, `key`, ot.name AS OFFICE_NAME, `manager`, `id` 
  FROM `ASSOCIATION_TABLE` at
       INNER JOIN OFFICE_TABLE ot
       ON ot.id = at.office
 WHERE `association`.`customer`=4;
```

Comment: +1: You were first, but mine was more pretty :p  Related: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: much prettier; thanks for the link :D

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Adam said, you can have a look at the official [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

I would also suggest that you look on google for a good SQL tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great site for giving examples of the different types of joins. Most likely you will want to use a left outer join.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.`name`, `key`, `office`, `manager`, `id` 
FROM `database`.`ASSOCIATION_TABLE`
JOIN `database`.`OFFICE_TABLE` o
USING (id)
WHERE `association`.`customer`=4;
```

Comment: That was the quick and dirty, I'd also recommend specifying aliases for each column and table you use.