# SQL query multiple tables

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 tables and I need to select the relative information, need some help with the query.

**Table 2** has `ID`, `MaskID` columns.

**Table 3** has `MaskID`, `MaskName`, `Total`

Assuming that I have an `ID` already given, how can I select the `ID`, `MaskName`, `Total` from the tables? How do I traverse though them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TSQL query would be:

```
SELECT t2.ID, t3.MaskName, t3.Total
FROM Table2 AS t2 INNER JOIN Table3 AS t3 ON (t2.MaskId = t3.MaskId)
WHERE ID = 123
```

Unsure what you mean by 'traverse' through them.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t2.ID,t3.MaskName,t3.Total
FROM Table2  t2 INNER JOIN  Table3 t3
ON t2.MaskID=t3.MaskID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a Join in your sql query. The [w3schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) has a page explaining how to use it.

Comment: it is a bad thing to mention w3schools as a resource on SO (see w3fools.com). There are much better resources out there including http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ID, b.MaskName, b.Total from 2 a INNER JOIN 3  b ON a.MaskID=b.MaskID WHERE ID='Given value'
```

This is a simple MySQl/T SQL/ PLSQL query. 
Just use an INNER JOIN on the two tables. A Join works by combining the two tables side by side. The INNER JOIN only outputs the result of the intersection of the two tables. That is, only those rows where the primary key and foreign key have a matching value.

In certain cases, you may want other rows outputted as well, for such cases look up LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, MaskName, Total from TABLE_2
inner join TABLE_3 on (TABLE_2.MaskID=TABLE_3.MaskID)
where ID=111
```

Answer (score -1):

you shoud use this query

`select ID,MaskName,Total from Table1 Inner join Table2 on Table1.MaskID = Table2.MaskId where ID = "given value"`

Comment: You should use the proper ANSI style JOIN syntax - don't just list tables in a comma-separated list - use the `INNER JOIN` syntax! It's the ANSI standard, it's much clearer to the reader!